# Registered an Assembly for COM, but only works on dev computer

Tags: silverlight, com, strongname, .net-assembly

Hey, I was wondering if you guys could see what is wrong/suggest a solution.

I have a dll Assembly for COM that I built with C#, and i am trying to get the COM object from Silverlight Out-of-browser. I want the siverlight application to be mobile between computers, so i put all the neccesary files in a zip along with a batch installer that does the followingto register the assembly:

cd %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
RegAsm.exe "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Homework Clock\windowsHook.dll" /tlb /nologo

My application finds the assembly and it works fine on my dev computer, but when I move my application to a test computer (along with the dll and any other neccesary files), my batch file says it registers successfully but the application doesn't find it.

However, when i rebuild the assembly with C# on the test computer and replace the dll i moved from the dev computer with the rebuilt dll, the application finds it fine. It would be convenient for my clients if they didn't have to rebuild the assembly using C# if they wish to use my application, so i was wondering if there was a way to fix this.

I looked into this problem for a while and thought it might be because my assembly wasn't a strong named assembly, since I think C# does that automatically, so i tried doing it in my batch file and it couldn't recognize the 'al' and 'sn' commands necessary to generate the cryptographic key to give an assembly a strong name, and i tried doing it in the 
'signing' tab in the C# project properties, but i encountered the same problem. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it works when you rebuild with VS is because it runs Regasm.exe with the /codebase option.  Required if you don't plan to put the assembly in the GAC.

Comment: Thanks, before when i tried codebase apparently i didn't have the right dll, but now it says "all types registered succesfully" and it works! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

C# does not automatically give assemblies a strong name. If you're using Visual Studio, open the project's Properties page, and look under the Signing tab. Check Sign the Assembly, and generate a new strong name key file. Build your project, and you should be able to do what you need to do with your existing batch file.

Comment: thanks, i got the dll strong named now, i thought i had to use the batch file commands :D

Comment: Strong name is not required if you don't plan to put the assembly to the GAC.